# SQSEvent object needed for SQS triggered lambda function in postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, amazon-sqs

I am trying to test my SQS triggered lambda function in my local machine using postman. I am able to call the function using postman but it requires SQSEvent type object as input. How do I provide this SQSEvent type input from postman?

How do I provide this SQSEvent type input from postman?

Comment: Please look at the documentation, which includes an example of what an SQSEvent looks like as a JSON object. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Answer (score 0):

As Mark pointed out in the comments, you have to pass a proper [event object format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).

Here is a small code snippet that helps you to generate the object: https://runkit.com/embed/yfml9p3wnlho which has the following code:

```js
const lambdaEventMock = require('lambda-event-mock');
const myMock = lambdaEventMock
  .sqs()
  .messageId('some-id')
  .receiptHandle('some-id')
  .eventSourceARN('some-arn')
  .body('body of sqs paylaod')
  .build();
console.log(JSON.stringify(myMock));
```

Alternatively, you can generate a mock payload in the Lambda Console UI on the Test tab.

[image]